# how to create single ear using ant for multiple environment

Tags: ant, websphere, ear

I have a requirement where in we have multiple properties files using which a EAR file is created for different environment like development,production etc. it takes around 45 minutes for the creation of ear in one specific environment which is a lot of time.What i want to do is create the EAR only once for all the environment and when it is deployed in the IBM WebSphere it should work.We use ant build for building the ear.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option would be to include a properties file in the EAR, and then adjust code in the EAR to use an env-entry to decide which properties file to use.  An administrator/developer can set the env-entry when deploying the application.

Comment: Can you please give an example for this.

Comment: How is the code that reads the properties file called?  Is it called by a servlet or EJB or what?  In the JavaEE component that calls that logic, you should define an `<env-entry>` in the corresponding web.xml or ejb-jar.xml.